# help with translation: a misterious space in the middle of sentence

Tags: translation, particles

怒りで単純になったお前の攻撃を     私が避けられないとでも？

I really didn't understand this sentence.
Why is there that space between "を"and "私"?

I'm not sure, but the whole thing is like:

"Because your anger, it was simple for me don't avoid your attack"

Comment: What is this quote from?

Comment: I am more worried about your translation than that space. Does that even make sense to you?

Comment: From a fan comic.
A guy get mad and attack another (who can stop time and the attack too).

Comment: I'm not sure... it seems without sense but the guy can stop time, so it isn't without sense so much... but probably is wrong, I know.
...
is it so much wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind the space; It will not be used in "normal" writing.  In manga, games, logos, etc., punctuations are often ignored.

Either ignore that space or replace it with a comma.  A comma is not necessary but it is not wrong to place one in there, either.

More importantly:

1) In understanding the sentence, you may need to add an imaginary 言うのか or 思うのか after the とでも.  It is left unsaid.  Since you did not know this, your translation ended up sounding strange.

2) You probably read the 避ける incorrectly, which is why you had "avoid" in your TL.  It is read よける, not さける in this context.

"Are you saying / Do you think that I cannot duck your attacks, which have become simplistic because of your anger?"

Comment: Oh, now it's clear.
Is the とでも+(言うのか or 思うのか) a rule or is only applicable in this case?

Comment: It is not a "rule" but unless 言うのか or 思うのか is said somewhere before と or とでも, you can be sure that it is left unsaid at the end of the sentence. The と is for quoting; therefore, you need a verb like "think", "say", "believe", "feel" to go with it.  In Japanese, however, these verbs are often left unsaid by us native speakers, so you would want to watch out for it. You will keep seeing/hearing this と, trust me.

Comment: And I'm starting to fear it ahaha
Anyway, thank you again.

Comment: Point 2) - What? Can't よける mean "avoid"? [edict](http://tangorin.com/general/%E9%81%BF%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B), [daijirin](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B)  - (1)出会わないように自分の位置を変える。  
「犬を―・けて通る」「自動車を危く―・けた」

"Duck" is specifically reducing one's height to avoid a blow, which I don't see as a limitation of よける, which covers a positional change in any direction.

Comment: この「[避]{よ}ける」は「身をかわす」って感じですが。。。（"dodge"とかかな、と・・。そういうのもavoidに含まれるんでしょうかね）

Comment: 広義的には含まれるんだろうけど、やはりこの文脈では「さける」と「よける」に互換性はないと考えます。「よける」と読むのが自然でしょう。我々母語話者は考えなくても直感的に判断できるのですが、学習者がそこまでの力を養うのは相当困難かと思います。

Comment: @TokyoNagoya "avoid"って、「(ひらりと/とっさに)(ボール・攻撃などから)身をかわす」っていう意味でも使えるんですか？

Comment: @ちょこれーと　使えないでしょう、基本は？「とっさの行動」を表すのには普通使わないはずです。avoid するために　dodge　したりするっていうのが自然な考え方では？この意味で先ほど「広義的には」という言い方をしたのです。

Comment: Right, I can agree that the element of 「とっさの行動」 implied by "dodge" is an improvement over "avoid" here. Are you saying that よける has more of an element of that than さける? The 用法 notes [here, for instance,](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/87351/m0u/%E3%81%95%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/) don't mention such a thing x.x ( To be clear, I don't need a reference, I just want to understand your own opinion :) )

Comment: @Hyperworm Yes, that is what I am saying.  There is some overlap in meaning between the two, but if you use さける to describe a とっさの行動, it does not sound very natural. The 用法 that you mentioned says at the bottom that 「よける」は、わきへ寄る、身をかわすなどの具体的な動作に重点がある。　「さける」　expresses more of an abstract idea of escaping from something. For describing quick body movements, よける would be the better word choice.